# Web application and TTS on IOS

Tags: ios, security, text-to-speech

We are building a web application on IOS a function of which is a calendar and when an appointment reminder triggers we do TTS and notify the user (or at least that is the intent) Currently we are unable to initiate the TTS until the User clicks on a button to acknowledge and start the TTS.. My Understanding is that this is a security restriction on IOS, Is there a way of sounding a TTS without the user having to acknowledge that there is is a message waiting.